# Fetching and reconstructing tree

Tags: algorithm, recursive-datastructures

I need some pointers in how I should go about solving below problem.

The problem is as following:

1. There are two persons A and B.
2. A has a large tree which he may update at any time, all nodes in tree are uniquely identifiable.
3. B will ask A about any one node and its ancestors upto n level above, n is always a valid random integer.
4. The above step gives B some information about the current structure of tree at A's end. B repeats the above step and overwrites nodes on his end if there is conflict or deletes the node if it was not found on A's end.
5. Now the problem is whats the optimal way of representing this information on B's end assuming B has limited space/memory? Can you provide some steps which helps to think about carrying these operations.

Example:

1. Lets suppose tree at A's end is as following:

```
└── 1
    ├── 2
    │   ├── 4
    │   └── 5
    └── 3
        └── 6
```

2. Now B asks for 2 and its one ancestor. B gets following info from A:

```
└── 1
    └── 2
```

The tree at B's end will look same as above.

3. Now lets assume A updates the tree to look as following:

```
└── 7
    ├── 2
    │   ├── 4
    │   └── 5
    └── 3
```

4. Now lets suppose B asks for 4 and one of its ancestor. B will get:

```
└── 2
    └── 4
```

B will incorporate above response from A into what it already knows and assume tree is as below:

```
└── 1
    └── 2
        └── 4
```

Please note above is not correct since node 1 is replaced with node 7 but B is doing as best as it can with known information.

5. Now lets assume B asks for node 8. Since node 8 does not exist, A will tell B such.
6. Now lets assume B asks for node 5 and two of its parents. B will get following response:

```
└── 7
    └── 2
        └── 5
```

B will assume tree at A's end looks like following:

```
└── 7
    └── 2
        ├── 4
        └── 5
```

Note that B overwrites node 1 with node 7.

7. Now lets assume A makes some more changes to the tree. The tree looks as following:

```
└── 8
    ├── 2
    │   ├── 4
    │   └── 5
    └── 3
```

B asks for node 3 and one of its ancestor. B will get following response:

```
└── 8
    └── 3
```

B will start maintaing two trees since it does not have enough information.
First tree will look like this:

```
└── 7
    └── 2
        ├── 4
        └── 5
```

Second tree will look like this:

```
└── 8
    └── 3
```

8. Now lets assume B asks about node 2 and one of its ancestor. B will get following response:

```
└── 8
    └── 2
```

B will now have enough information to merge the previous two trees into one. Tree at B's end will look like this:

```
└── 8
    ├── 2
    │   ├── 4
    │   └── 5
    └── 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "n parents"?  Does a node have multiple parents, or do you mean the ancestor of n generations above?  This question is very hard to answer without specific examples.  Finally, you should define "optimal" in what way: computation complexity, amount of memory, etc.

Comment: @KotaMori Please check my examples, let me know if I can provide some more.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Given this information, a hash table mapping a node to its parent would be good for the operations and also simplify the implementation.  But the hash table may not be optimal for the memory efficiency.  If the space is critical then linked list would be better.